# Why do I get this error in my logcat when I try to post JSON data?

Tags: android, json

This is the code my Android application uses to post JSON data. When I execute it, I get the following error in my logcat. Why?

[image]

Comment: I already added it. Plz check

Comment: you are getting json Parse Exception 
get Your Logs In JasonParseException try catch block

Comment: U are not getting any sort of resource ...check your own log status ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Logcat says `org.json.JSONException: No value for success`

that means that you are **trying to retrieve a value from the JSONObject using success that doesn't exist** in the `JSONObject`

Use [`has("");`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) to check if key is present in Json

```
String success ="":
if (Jobj.has("success")) {
    success = Jobj.getString("success");
}
```